# Why does the axiom of choice imply the existence of a unique God?

Tags: philosophy, thomas-aquinas, summa-theologica, existence-of-god, anselm

The following is paraphrased from *A Passion for Mathematics* by Clifford A. Pickover (read in Kiefer Sutherland's voice): ([mathjax here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2933055/))

**Theorem**: The axiom of choice is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629464) to the existence of a unique God (St. Anselm, Aquinas, and others).

> Proof:
>
> First, suppose the axiom of choice. Partially order the set of subsets
>   of the set of all properties of objects by inclusion. This set has
>   maximal elements. God is by definition (due to Anselm) a maximal
>   element set.
>
> We prove existence: God $\subseteq$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$, so
>   God $=$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$. Therefore, God exists.
>
> We prove uniqueness: Let God and God′ be two gods, then God $\cup$
>   God′ $\supseteq$ God (due to Aquinas) $\implies$ God $\cup$ God′ = God
>   $\implies$ God $\subseteq$ God′ Similarly, God′ $\subseteq$
>   God. Therefore, God is unique.
>
> Second, suppose the existence of a unique God, omnipotent, omniscient
>   and amoral (or omnibenevolent. It does not matter for this context).
>   Given an index set $R$ and collection of sets
>   ${A_{\alpha}}_{{\alpha \in R}}$, pray that the unique God picks,
>   by omnipotence, $x_{\alpha} \in A_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in A$.
>   Then $${x_{\alpha}}_{\alpha \in R} \in \prod_{\alpha \in R} A_{\alpha}$$ as required.

Questions:

1. What is a "maximal element set"? I could not find this online. I do not remembering learning this in philosophy of religion class when I was in bachelor's.
2. In existence, how does God $\subseteq$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$ imply God $=$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$? I guess that we have somehow already had God $\supseteq$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$.
3. In uniqueness, why do we have have that God $\subseteq$ God′ instead of God $\supseteq$ God′?
4. Is uniqueness required for the second direction? I can think of only the unique choice of $x_{\alpha}$ or something of the sort.

I think I am fine with the second direction.

Update: I think [this link](http://ion.uwinnipeg.ca/~currie/logic.pdf) might have some answers.

Comment: You can't use mathjax here.

Comment: @curiousdannii This is why I put "mathjax here" on top.

Comment: Well you should edit it to make it readable. You can use `<sub>` and `<sup>`, and several (probably most) of the symbols are in unicode.

Comment: Well the maximal set of a powerset if of course the original set itself. That is unique. What does it have to do with axiom of choice or God? I understand the last part tries to say that an all-mighty God implies axiom of choice, but doesn't that basically just mean axiom of choice is assumed?

Answer (score 1):

I won't make any statements about the mathematical, philosophical or theological implications of the *proof*. But I can help you with the maths (this would better done on math.SE).

1. Make a order of the sets: A set **A** is *greater or equal* than a set **B** iff **B** is a subset or equal of **A**. A maximal element set (God) is maximal in this order, so it has no set that is a superset to it.
2. As you said we have God $\supseteq$ God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$ as existence is a property, God $\cup$ ${$existence$}$ is *greater or equal* than God, but God is maximal (see 1).
3. I would it also do the other way around. But it works than too ("Similarly ...").
4. I don't think uniqueness is required, but we have it so, why not assuming it?

Answer (score -1):

The question has a Catagory mistake.

Like dividing any number by zero.